# How can I generate 5 random numbers from 01 to 99 and give today's date as the 6th number?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I need to create a 6-digit number of which 5 will be drawn from 1 to 99 and the sixth will be today's date (only a day, not a month), and put it in label1. I'm a beginner so I'm sorry.

Comment: What if the day has two digits?

Comment: oh, yes, I did not think about it. if possible, do so so that the 5 number is deleted or replaced with a date.

Comment: 5th number replaced with a date

Comment: Create an instance of the `Random` class, create 4 or 5 digits from it (depending on whether the current day is >= 10) using `random.Next` and append the day.

Comment: If you intend to use this like a date, consider creating a number from 0-99 for the year (or go whole hog, and use a range like 1950-2050), then a range like 1-12 as the month, and then play with the day. But, remember that months can have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days (and that the rules for 29 are complex (1900 was not a leap year, for example))

Comment: It really would help if you explained what you will be using this for, as I suspect you are going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in an imperative style:

```
    var r = new Random();
    var text = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
    while (text.Length < 6)
    {
        // identify the next random prefix string between 1 and 99 inclusive
        var prefix = (r.Next(99) + 1).ToString();

        // reduce the prefix to the first character (1-9) if it would exceed the target total of 6
        if (prefix.Length + text.Length > 6)
        {
            prefix = prefix.Substring(0, 1);
        }
        text = prefix + text;
    }
    label1.Text = text;
```

Or alternatively in a functional style:

```
    var r = new Random();
    label1.Text = string.Concat(Generate(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(), i => (r.Next(99) + 1).ToString()).SelectMany(i => i.Reverse()).Take(6).Reverse());
```

The latter of which assumes you have access to a generator function similar to:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(T start, Func<T, T> step)
    {
        var current = start;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = step(current);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution assumes 1-99 as is specified in the OP details and not 01-99 as is specified in the subject title